# SSRS 2016 Report Manager Blank Page

Tags: ssrs-2016

I recently installed SSRS 2016 on a Windows 2012 R2 machine and when I go to the Report manager URL I get a blank page.  I used the defaults when configuring SSRS except I changed the port from 80 to 8080.  The version of SQL Server that SSRS is using is 2016 SP1 and is located on the same server.  I'm a local admin on the box.  SSRS is installed on the default instance (there is a 2012 and 2014 SQL Server named instance on the box as well but no other installation of SSRS).

The blank page doesn't leave me much to go on in regards to figuring out what the issue is.  I've come across a few other posts where people have reported similar issues with the usual cause being changes to virtual directories or insufficient permissions.  I don't think that's the issue here but a blank screen doesn't tell me much either way.

Any suggestions on what would cause of a blank page for Report Mgr or suggestions on how to trouble shoot would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

By default, the `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration` is enabled on the server. This causes the ReportManager site to be entirely blank. If I look at the Page Source in IE Developer Console, all HTML is shown.

Went to `Server Manager -> Local Server -> IE Enhanced Security Configuration` and turned it `off`. Report Pages are now displayed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue opening the Report Manager, it turned out to be a browser related issue.

I could open the `http://[servername]/ReportServer` just fine using `Internet Explorer` but when I attempted to open the `http://[servername]/Reports` page it would just sit at a blank page.

I first attempted to turn off `Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration` using the `Server manager` then navigating to `Local Server -> IE Enhanced Security Configuration` and turned it `Off` for Administrators (as I was an admin). But the issue was still unresolved.

That did not work as I was still using `Internet Explorer`. As soon as I switched to `Microsoft Edge` the problem was resolved.

See [MS Document - Browser support for Reporting Services and Power View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/browser-support-for-reporting-services-and-power-view?view=sql-server-ver16#browser-requirements-for-the-web-portal)

Comment: Internet Explorer does not run in administrator context by default, even if you are logged in as an admin. You must start it explicitly as administrator. In most scenarios it is safer to disable IE ESC for non-admins as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your URL in the trusted sites in Internet options